# A library I no longer use crashes the app on startup. How to remove it completely? Xcode / Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I installed a library using cocoapods and decided I no longer need it and deleted. However, when I try to launch the app, it crashes with this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/LiquidFloatingActionButton.framework/LiquidFloatingActionButton
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/98CA3428-C3A7-45F3-BA24-E91D51D10503/MyProject.app/MyProject
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

LiquidFloatingActionButton is the name of the framework I deleted. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: how did you go about deleting the library?

Comment: Did you deleted manually? or you removed Lib. from podfile and update the pod again?

Comment: I did remove the corresponding line from Podfile. Then tried to pod install.

Comment: Try to clean the project shift+command+k and then option+command+shift+K

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Build phases and remove the framework from "Link Binary with Libraries"

then remove any associated file in your project directory

Also, in your Build phases you must have some copy file/ run script / bundle resource phases associated with that cocoapod.. remove that as well

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how did you remove your framework you should select "REMOVE FROM REFERENCE ".Well you just remove your project from Link Binary with Libraries and also need to clean your drive data then check your framework search path in build setting.
if all theses not works then update your cocoa pod.